# java cannot persis an entity, maybe because of boolean field

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I'm trying to persist this entity, declaration

```
@Entity
@Table(schema="app")
public class Remainder {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
private int amount;
private String description;
private boolean repeat;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="CATEGORY")
private Category category;

@Column(name="DUE_DATE")
private LocalDate dueDate;
```

I use the persist() method of EntityManager. I get this exception:

```
[EL Warning]: 2015-08-30 11:14:56.341--UnitOfWork(1824877389)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REPEAT, CATEGORY) VALUES (35, 'qeqdfqd', '2015-08-31', 0, 'Electricity')' at line 1
Error Code: 1064
Call: INSERT INTO app.REMAINDER (AMOUNT, DESCRIPTION, DUE_DATE, REPEAT, CATEGORY) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
bind => [5 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(lite.money.entities.Remainder@326db21e)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REPEAT, CATEGORY) VALUES (35, 'qeqdfqd', '2015-08-31', 0, 'Electricity')' at line 1
Error Code: 1064
Call: INSERT INTO app.REMAINDER (AMOUNT, DESCRIPTION, DUE_DATE, REPEAT, CATEGORY) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
bind => [5 parameters bound]
```

this is the table declaration

```
CREATE TABLE `remainder` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `amount` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `repeat` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `DUE_DATE` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_REMAINDER-Category_CATEGORY_SUB-ID_idx` (`category`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_REMAINDER-Category_CATEGORY_SUB-ID` FOREIGN KEY (`category`) REFERENCES `category` (`SUB_CATEGORY`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I think the problem is with the boolean field, Please Help

Comment: Have you tried to execute this query directly in your database? You have a DML-query as it was executed by jpa, you have all the values, and now if you'll try to do it by yourself, just connected to your DB, then you can change or exclude some values to find those one, which causes an exception.

Comment: @karimmohsen the REPEAT is false and category is an entity (Electricity is the ID), so it is all set.

Comment: @Stanislav thanks man for taking the time, I fix it

Comment: @usertest Repeat is a reserved keyword so you can use backticks arround that name `REPEAT`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fix it by renaming the column REPEAT to repeated, because REPEAT is a reserved workd in mysql.